# Adding multipart file as an attachment to an email in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, email-attachments

I want to send an email from Spring Boot with a pdf attachment. I have received the pdf file as a multipart file from a POST call.

Here's my controller class so far (`sendEmails` method is included in `emailService` service):

```
@PostMapping("/email")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendEmail(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile pdfFile,
                                       @RequestParam("email") String email) {


        boolean result = this.emailService.sendEmails(email, pdfFile);
        
        if (result) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Email sent...");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Email sending failed");
        }
    }
```

And here's sendEmails method:

```
public boolean sendEmails(String reciever, MultipartFile pdf) {

        try {
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
            mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
            mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(Objects.requireNonNull("587")));
            mailSender.setUsername("~my email~");
            mailSender.setPassword("~my pw~");

            Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", "true");
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

            mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);

            sendEmailAndUpdate(reciever, pdf, mailSender);

            System.out.println("Email Sent  Successfully...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("EmailService File Error" + e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

Now, in the `sendEmailAndUpdate` method I have the reciever's email address, the pdf (as a MultipartFile), and the JavaMailSender. Here's this method so far:

```
private void sendEmailAndUpdate(String recieverEmail, MultipartFile file, JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        try {
            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject("PDF email");
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(~My Email~);
            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(recieverEmail);
            
            mimeMessageHelper.setText("This is email body");

            // Code for attaching the PDF goes here

            mailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());

        } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Here I want to attach the pdf file (which I have as a MultipartFile) to the email. This might be a noob question and I might be missing something obvious, but I'm new to this and I couldn't find any resources online on how to do this. Can anyone link me to such resource or provide with a solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attached directly

```
 mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("fileName", file);
```

`MultipartFile` already extend class of `InputStreamSource`

```
 public interface MultipartFile extends InputStreamSource {
```

Answer (score 0):

By using MultipartFile file as part of the model class will also work.

```
package com.techgeeknext.request;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NotificationEmail {
    private String to;
    private String cc;
    private String subject;
    private String bodyMsg;
    private MultipartFile file;
    private boolean isHtmlMsg;
}
```

And in Controller class use post method with ModelAttribute.

```
package com.techgeeknext.controller;

import com.techgeeknext.request.NotificationEmail;
import com.techgeeknext.service.NotificationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class NotificationController {

    @Autowired
    NotificationService notificationService;

    @PostMapping("/sendNotificationEmail")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendNotificationEmail(@ModelAttribute NotificationEmail notificationEmail) {
        boolean emailSent = false;
        if (notificationEmail.getFile()!=null) {
            emailSent = notificationService.sendNotificationEmailWithAttachment(notificationEmail, notificationEmail.getFile());
        } else {
            emailSent = notificationService.sendTextNotificationEmail(notificationEmail);
        }
        if (emailSent) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Email sent.");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("Error occurred while sending email.");
        }
    }
}
```

This [Example](https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring-email) explain above implementation in detail.